# MongoDB "service" on clean Redhat can not be started

Tags: linux, mongodb, service, installation, redhat

I just bring up `Redhat 6.5 64-bit` from AWS and did the below things:

- Disabled SELinux
- Disabled Iptables
- All ports opened in Security Group
- Rebooted

Then i just followed, both of the below instructions:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat-or-centos/

I tried the both Links separately after clean installations again.

Here is the version:

```
[root@www.example.com ~]# mongod --version
db version v2.6.4
2014-08-19T04:35:58.234-0400 git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
```

**THEN HERE IS THE PROBLEM**:

```
[root@www.example.com ~]# service mongod start
Starting mongod:                          [FAILED]
```

And here are the logs:

```
[root@www.example.com ~]# tail /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2014-08-19T04:30:07.671-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.671-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

This is quite a very clean installation.
What is happening please.

Note:

```
[root@www.example.com ~]# ll /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mongod mongod 0 Aug 19 04:32 /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock
```

Comment: The logs show the end of a shutdown. What's further up? Any errors? Can you post your config file for mongod?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to [SERVER-14679: (CentOS 7/RHEL 7) init.d script should create directory for pid file if it is missing](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14679).

Here is what to do:

Edit the file `/etc/init.d/mongod` according to [this diff which is the solution to the linked ticket](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/50ca596ace0b1390482408f1b19ffb1f9170cab6).

Answer (score 0):

My fix on CentOS7

```
`#`systemctrl enable mongod
`#`systemctrl start  mongod
`#`systemctrl status mongod
 this should return a fail status
`#`systemctrl stop mongod

`#`rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

`#`chown -R mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
`#`chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongodb

`#`systemctrl start mongod

now test 

`#`mongo
example
MongoDB shell version v3.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.3
```